# MongoDB group and count object in document array

Tags: database, mongodb

I need to group and count array in a object.
I tried a lot of things, but cannot the solution.

I have a mongodb document like that:

```json
[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "A",
        "connected" : [
            {
                "iid" : 1,
                "risk" : "high"
            },
            {
                "iid" : 2,
                "risk" : "high"
            },
            {
                "iid" : 3,
                "risk" : "low"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "B",
        "connected" : [
            {
                "iid" : 4,
                "risk" : "medium"
            },
            {
                "iid" : 5,
                "risk" : "medium"
            },
            {
                "iid" : 6,
                "risk" : "low"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "name":"C"
    }
]
```

I want to a query which give me a result like that:

```json
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"A",
        "count": {
            "high" : 2,
            "low" : 1
        }
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "name":"B",
        "count": {
            "medium" : 2,
            "low" : 1
        }
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "name":"C"
    }
]
```

I tried "$group" in "$addFields" aggregation query, but it doesn't except "$group".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do following in an aggregation pipeline:

1. `$unwind` `connected` array
2. `$group` by `id` and `connected.risk` to get the count
3. `$group` by `id` to put the results in an array of {k: , v: }
4. use `$arrayToObject` to get back the form you want

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$connected"
  },
  {
    // group by raw id and risk to get the count first
    $group: {
      _id: {
        id: "$id",
        risk: "$connected.risk"
      },
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // regroup the counts by putting them back to an array
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.id",
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      count: {
        "$addToSet": {
          k: "$_id.risk",
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // convert the result array back to the form you want
    "$project": {
      name: 1,
      count: {
        "$arrayToObject": "$count"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Nti44S_saNa) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks, it works good. Beside, I want to include documents which doesn't have `connected` object like : `{ "id": 3, "name": "C" }`. As a result I want to get one of `{ "id": 3, "name": "C" }` or `{ "id": 3, "name": "C", "count": null }`. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You will need to handle the null cases by using `$ifNull` and `$cond`. [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Tbh8tM44Tvx)

Answer (score 0):

Thansk for @ray, I've found the solution and added some custom options like;

- Get `connected` object in the result
- Adding `total` count in `count` field.

If someone need to help with these problems, can check this reference:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/gRIOVj4A8Bh

The result is somethint like that:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "A",
        "connected": [
            {
                "iid": 1,
                "risk": "high"
            },
            {
                "iid": 2,
                "risk": "high"
            },
            {
                "iid": 3,
                "risk": "low"
            }
        ],
        "count": {
            "high": 2,
            "low": 1,
            "total": 3
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "B",
        "connected": [
            {
                "iid": 4,
                "risk": "medium"
            },
            {
                "iid": 5,
                "risk": "medium"
            },
            {
                "iid": 6,
                "risk": "low"
            }
        ],
        "count": {
            "low": 1,
            "medium": 2,
            "total": 3
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "C",
        "count": {
            "total": 0
        }
    }
]
```

If `connected` object doesn't wanted, it can be added in `$unset` list in the end of query.